# Blazor - Passing a function to dynamic component

Tags: c#, components, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-component

I'd like to have a fluent communication between components via DynamicComponent in Blazor.
Thus I'd like to know whether its possible to pass a function to a DynamicComponent since now it doesn't know that the *would be* rendered components need a function to fully operate. All suggestions are welcome.

`Index.razor`

```
@page "/"

/*This is where I'd like for all of my components to get rendered cleanly*/
<DynamicComponent Type="selectedType" /*Here I'd like to pass a function "GoToComponent"*/ />

@code {
    public void GoToComponent(string name)
    {
        selectedType = Type.GetType($"Namespace.Pages.{name}");
    }
}
```

`LandingComponent.razor`

```
<p @onclick="() => OnClickFunction.InvokeAsync("First")">GO TO FIRST</p>
<p @onclick="() => OnClickFunction.InvokeAsync("Second")">GO TO SECOND</p>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnClickFunction { get; set; }
}
```

`FirstComponent.razor`

```
<p @onclick="() => OnClickFunction.InvokeAsync("Landing")">GO TO LANDING</p>
<p @onclick="() => OnClickFunction.InvokeAsync("Second")">GO TO SECOND</p>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnClickFunction { get; set; }
}
```

`SecondComponent.razor`

```
<p @onclick="() => OnClickFunction.InvokeAsync("First")">GO TO FIRST</p>
<p @onclick="() => OnClickFunction.InvokeAsync("Landing")">GO TO LANDING</p>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnClickFunction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know this is already resolved, but as I was having similar issues I wrote a blog post going into a bit more detail... might come in useful for someone in the future: https://mariomucalo.com/dynamic-components-in-blazor-with-parameters-and-event-handling/

Comment: @MarioMucalo Can you update the github link in your blog.
https://github.com/mucalo/DynamicComponentsDemo - This is returns 404

Comment: @Aakash The link was correct, but for some reason I left the GitHub repo to be private. Now it is public again. Thanks for catching that! https://github.com/mucalo/DynamicComponentsDemo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a revised `Landing.razor`.  `First` and `Second` should be similar.

```
<p @onclick="() => OnClick(typeof(First))">GO TO FIRST</p>
<p @onclick="() => OnClick(typeof(Second))">GO TO SECOND</p>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Type> OnClickFunction { get; set; }

    private void OnClick(Type type)
    {
        OnClickFunction.InvokeAsync(type);
    }
}
```

And Index:

```
@page "/"
<DynamicComponent Type=this.selectedType Parameters=this.parameters/>

@code {
    private Type selectedType = typeof(Landing);

    private Dictionary<string, object> parameters => new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "OnClickFunction", EventCallback.Factory.Create<Type>(this, GoToComponent)}
    };

    public void GoToComponent(Type type)
    {
        this.selectedType = type;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried to use Parameters, but probably not well enough :). Thank you for the great answer.

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis, Could you please check this question for me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72880729/dynamiccomponent-send-value-from-child-to-the-parent